Run a swagger api in docker
I have managed to set up a docker with swagger-editor and swagger-ui, and they load my own api.
The problem is that when I run the execution tests, they give error.
I've got this as servers in my api
  "servers": [
    {
      "description": "Servidor Local",

      "url": "http://localhost:9490"
    },
    {
      "description": "Servidor Local 2",

      "url": "http://localhost:8484"
    }
  ]

docker-compose.yml
version: "3.3"
services:
  swagger-editor:
    image: swaggerapi/swagger-editor
    container_name: "swagger-editor"
    ports:
      - "8481:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./swagger/openapi.json:/openapi.json
    environment:
      SWAGGER_JSON: /openapi.json
      SWAGGER_FILE: /openapi.json

  swagger-ui:
    image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui
    container_name: "swagger-ui"
    ports:
      - "8482:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./swagger/openapi.json:/openapi.json
    environment:
      SWAGGER_JSON: /openapi.json
      # API_URL: ""

  swagger-api:
    image: danielgtaylor/apisprout
    container_name: "swagger-api"
    ports:
      - "8483:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./swagger/openapi.json:/openapi.json
    command: /openapi.json


  swagger-nginx:
    image: nginx:mainline-alpine
    container_name: "swagger-nginx"
    ports:
      - "8484:8084"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf


nginx default.conf
server {
  listen 8084;
  server_name localhost;
  location / {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, Authorization, Accept";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
    proxy_pass "http://localhost:8483";
  }
}

I have tried several variations on this configuration.
I expect to at least access my api, no network error, ideally to save the data sent to me.
